# Разгадать кроссворд, используя сервис

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, веб-программирование, requests

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здравствуйте! Я понял как отправлять данные на сервер и получать с него ответ, но это касается только того, если я отправляю маску в таком виде "а-т------я", в случае, указанном в задании, я предполагаю, что данные буквы можно закинуть в переменные, а переменные в список. Все задумки укажу в коде, они работают, если я не подключаю веб, а использую список из слов (и то, ситуация с 6 и пустым местом не доработана). Слова могут быть по горизонтали и вертикали (как я понимаю первое по вертикали - автор, по горизонтали - автократия) А теперь к сути вопроса. Как мне реализовать так, чтобы это работало с веб-версией (выше до комментария)? Код прилагаю:

```
import requests as rq
import json
params = {"mask": "а-т------я"}#params ={"mask": lst} лиcт соответственно 
responce = rq.get("https://poncy.ru/crossword/crossword-solve.jsn?", params=params)
data = json.loads(responce.text)
print(data["words"])
#далее задумка
a = ("а", "в", "г")
b = ("е", "и", "к")
c = ("л", "н", "о")
d = ("п", "р", "с")
e = ("т", "у", "щ")
f = ("ь", "я", "")
lst = [a, a, e, c, b, d, a, e, b, f]#первое слово по горизонтали
dc = ["автомобиль", "автократия", "барабанщик", "мототуризм", "автограф", "ориентир"]#проверяю есть ли слово среди данного списка
 
for word in dc:
    if len(word) <= len(lst):
        for key, char_set in enumerate(lst):
            char = word[key] if key <= len(word) + 1 else ""
            if char not in char_set:
                break
        else:
            print(word)
```

UPD: еще доработал это добро, теперь все упирается в количество слов, если их больше 504, то я не факт что найду это слово среди всех, то есть, с маской, указанной в коде найду, а с пустой "----------" - нет.
Обновленный код:

```
import requests as rq
import json
params = {"mask": "А--------Я"}#params ={"mask": lst} лиcт соответственно 
responce = rq.get("https://poncy.ru/crossword/crossword-solve.jsn?", params=params)
data = json.loads(responce.text)
lst_ten = data["words"]
a = ("А", "В", "Г")
b = ("Е", "И", "К")
c = ("Л", "Н", "О")
d = ("П", "Р", "С")
e = ("Т", "У", "Щ")
f = ("Ь", "Я", "")
lst = [a, a, e, c, b, d, a, e, b, f]
for word in lst_ten:
    if len(word) <= len(lst):
        for key, char_set in enumerate(lst):
            char = word[key] if key <= len(word) + 1 else ""
            if char not in char_set:
                break
        else:
            print(word)
```

Comment: Upd, если буду делать через "или", то выводится по первой букве, если по "и", по второй, можно как-то сделать чтобы обе участвовали?                                                                                                      
`import requests as rq
import json
a = "а" or "в"
b = "-"
t = "т"
i = "я"
v = "в"
f = "и"
lst = [a, b, b, b, b, b, b, t, f, i]
lst_join = ''.join(lst)
params = {"mask": lst_join}
responce = rq.get("https://poncy.ru/crossword/crossword-solve.jsn?", params=params)
data = json.loads(responce.text)
print(data["words"])`